# redirect - 301 with dynamic urls and question marks

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have several redirects in my htaccess file like

```
redirect 301 /detail.php?id=101 http://www.example.com/product/costume-didnt-fit-im-stuck-shirt/
```

I use this method frequently, but this time it seems to not be working and I am thinking it is the dynamic url. Is there a way to have this method of redirect with this type of URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot match query string in `Redirect` directive. Use `mod_rewrite` rules instead:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=[0-9]+
RewriteRule ^detail\.php$ http://www.example.com/product/costume-didnt-fit-im-stuck-shirt/? [L,R=301,NC]
```

Comment: ugh ok Ill try that, I have about 100 of them so I have some work to do :)

Comment: What URL did you try to test it and what is location of this .htaccess?

Comment: www.fatguyshirts.com/.htaccess

Comment: I asked 2 question in my comment :)

Comment: Here is an old url that should be redirecting `http://www.fatguyshirts.com/detail.php?id=3` to `http://www.fatguyshirts.com/product/winning-fight-anorexia/`

Comment: I answered it :) later that is

Comment: But `id=3` is not same `id=101`. DO you want any `id=some-number` to be redirected?

Comment: I have several different id's and I applied all the different urls to redirect to in my example. That not right?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48307/discussion-between-cesar-bielich-and-anubhava)